# HTML login form : provide username,autofill password

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete, passwords

I need a login form where I just need to provide my username,cause it will remember my password and automatically fill in the password field (Ex. Like in gmail auth).

How could I achieve that?

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of behavior is usually defined by the browser. However there are a few things you can do to improve this behavior.

Make sure you use descriptive names for your form

```
<label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" />
<label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" />
```

Using these names can really make a difference. I for example use the Opera browser, and in my settings, I've set a few values. For example "name", "address", "telephone number". And opera will look for fields that have equivalent names, and I can let Opera fill it in for me.

**The next two things are only supported in Internet Explorer, and I would by no use advice to implement them without thinking about it**

*I mean, I think it's no harm implementing them. It just gives a little more support to Internet Explorer users, but I wouldn't rely on them*

Also Internet Explorer supports an attribute called `autocomplete`, which you can control whether IO should autocomplete the `input`. You can use it as following

```
<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="on" /> <!--Enabled-->
<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" /> <!--Disabled-->
```

Also (an IE only feature, I think...) is the support of vCards. You can add an attribute `VCARD_NAME` and it lets the browser fill in the appropriate vCard value. For example

```
<input type="text" name="email" VCARD_NAME="vCard.Email" />
```

Comment: I knew autocomplete and I guessed was a browser defined behaviour.. in my form i have "email" input and "Password" but when I type in my email the password doesn't get filled in my "Password" input field..As the browser does for gmail or I dont know.. facebook

Comment: Well your browser doesn't store your password in advance. You need to login atleast once, then say "yeah I want to save it for this website" and the next time you login, it will try to autocomplete it for you.

Answer (score 9):

A note for people to avoid banging their heads against the wall: Chrome won't save and suggest passwords on untrusted sites.

As such, if you are testing on your local server at `https://localhost`, and you haven't generated a valid and trusted certificate, you won't be able to test this feature of Chrome's.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't autofill your password, it is your browser that does this.

What can help is using something like [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) but you need to leave it to the individual users whether or not they want their password remembered.